# I put the xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar into path and it says another exception while reading .xslx file using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I put the xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar into path and it says another exception while reading .xslx file using apache poi.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:149)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:136)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:54)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:98)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:199)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:53)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:176)
        at setTargetPlan.setTask(setTargetPlan.java:152)
        at userVerification.main(userVerification.java:204)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as your earlier problem.

For each ClassNotFound exception, search for the jar on the site below which contains this class and put the jar in your classpath

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.dom4j.DocumentException shows you need dom4j.jar